# Zend framework plugin controller send variable to controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

i have a zend framework controller plugin and in the preDispatch function i have a variable that i want to access it in my front controller, how do i do that ?

ZF1

Thanks!

Comment: there is no code, hypothetically how do i send a variable from plugin to front controller
$foo = 'yes';
i want to access $foo in my front controller

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171849/how-to-get-controller-from-within-controller-plugin-in-zendframework-2

Comment: ah sorry this is for ZF1, i'll edit the question..

Comment: SO isn't a free guide / tutorial service.

Comment: yea thanks for that Epodax, your response is the most helpful ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple `echo Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getPlugin('Plugin_Class_Name')->variable;`

Comment: Thanks Max P. this is what i was looking for! :)
i've search for it everywhere, google, SO, ZF docs ... could not find anything on it ..